# PHP Q: How to save config values using external global variables?

Tags: php, post, asp-classic, save, global-variables

I'm new to PHP.
When I using classic ASP the Application['...'] object is very useful to save configuration value on web server.

**Implementaion here :**

```
<?php
function GetConfiguration()
{
    return $GLOBALS['config'];
}

if($_POST['CONFIG'] != "")
    $GLOBALS['config'] = $_POST['CONFIG'];
if($_POST['LOCK'] != "")
    $GLOBLAS['lock'] = $_POST['LOCK'];

echo "CONFIG : " . $GLOBALS['config'] . "<br>";
echo "LOCK   : " . $GLOBALS['lock'] . "<br>";

$configpath = GetConfiguration();
echo $configpath . "<br>";

$configrealpath = realpath($configpath);

$fp = @fopen($confirealpath, "r");
$configvalue = @fread($fp, filesize($configrealpath));
@fclose($fp);

if($configvalue == "")
    echo "Config path is not availble or cannot read.<br>";
else
{
    //My operation...
}
?>
```

After set values using POST parameters, I can't get correct value on another PC calling web.  I think it is cause of session.  Is there any way to save config using global variables not saving data as file?

Comment: you will need to save the values to a file of DB

Comment: I think there is no variable or object to use in different client. If you are using DB, it will help you to save config values. but there is some limitation in use.

Comment: @Shadow Wizard, Thank you. But I don't want to save value as file. Please tell me another method.

Comment: @Kaizen I'm afraid there is no way like in classic ASP, PHP simply does not have such a thing.